# how to set refresh Interval In Application

Tags: java, android

hi I am new in android. I have created one application and I use preferences for setting. I have used list preferences set  to 1,10 ,60 minute.  Now i want to apply a function so that another activity should be refreshed in each time interval.

```
beerPref2
                .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                            Object newValue) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        final ListPreference listrefresh = (ListPreference) preference;
                        final int idx = listrefresh
                                .findIndexOfValue((String) newValue);

                        if (idx == 0) {

                        } else if (idx == 1) {
                            // System.out.println("2");

                        } else if (idx == 2) {
                            System.out.println("3");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("4");
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
```

This is code for preferences screen. Now i have another class named  DetailPage. This class we have to reload. Can You please complete this code. I have tried much but not able to do. I am new in android and want to implement this. Please help me and complete this code. How i will load another class in certain time interval? I mean to say that if we select 1 minute then the activity should reload each 1 minute. If we select 10 minutes then application should reload each 10 minute and ... Help me to implement this

Comment: This DetailPage is this an activity and what is the reload a function that you execute?

Comment: yes its already executed

Comment: i want to apply thread how will apply thread for each time interval

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

With `Handler`s you can post `Runnable`s to be executed at some time in the future.

There is also the possibility to register at android's alarm service, but that's not what you want, i guess.

Comment: actully we want that if we select 1 minute then activity should refresh in each 1 minute or if we select 10 minute then activity should refresh in each 10 minute.

Comment: You can do this with a Handler. Or even better a HandlerThread, if it should not be done on the main thread. With a Handler you would write a Runnable that does your update and post an instance of that to Handler.postDelayed( runnableInstance, interval ). Then it will be executed in _interval_ millies. Inside the runnable post it again at the end to have cyclic behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, quite busy right now. Also have a look at @Iggy's answer. It's another good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in an activity you can use the ScheduledFuture class from android to execute an runnable at a fixed interval with the scheduleAtFixedRate function see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html
for more information

```
public class DetailPage extends Activity { 
    private final ScheduledExecutorService checkCurrentTime=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);  
    private ScheduledFuture scheduledTimeChecker ;

    private final Runnable timeChecker = new Runnable() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            doInBackground(str); 
        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        startTimeSchecker();
    } 

    protected Void doInBackground(String Url) { 
        detailed_news = dh.get_detail_news(id[i],catagoryid); 
        allData.add(detailed_news); 
    } 

    private void startTimeSchecker(){        
        if(scheduledTimeChecker==null ||scheduledTimeChecker.isCancelled()){        
            scheduledTimeChecker =checkCurrentTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeChecker, 10, 60,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please tell ur email id so that i can post u code because its not working

Comment: please add code in given code so that i can implement it easily just add only for 1 minute

Comment: is it still not working? you can ask a question via stackoverflow

Comment: if you post the skeleton of your activity I can integrate it

Comment: public class DetailPage extends Activity 
{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//here we are geting str
doInBackground(str);
}

protected Void doInBackground(String Url) 
   {


detailed_news = dh.get_detail_news(id[i],catagoryid);
      allData.add(detailed_news);



}

}

Comment: This code results in error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`